# Top bar keeps displaying my total rep gain for the day

Tags: bug

Whenever I open a tab and leave it unattended, if my rep changes due to an upvote, the top bar now shows my **entire rep gain for the day** instead of just the normal rep change (e.g. +290 instead of +10)

---

I'm using Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 8.1

Comment: I've been having this problem as well, using Chrome 59 on Ubuntu 16.04 & Chrome on Android Jellybean.

Comment: @Mithrandir - It's quite disconcerting. I keep thinking someone's given me a bounty :-)

Comment: Mine works fine :)

Comment: No-repro here. Is it only happening on SFF, or on other sites (e.g. ones where you haven't repcapped) too? You might want to post on main meta to increase the chances of attracting a dev's attention quickly.

Comment: -1 for using Windows 8

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I've yet to see a reason to upgrade.

Comment: I had this problem the other days. Haven't had any rep today to confirm if it still on-going. If some one gives me an up-vote a I can confirm :P.

Comment: Mine works BTW. after reviewing prior rep change in dropdown, i see zero now.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To or like some of us at work on work issued computers we no choice in using windows 8

Comment: 290? **290**? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Möoz - I'm on 290 again today. Hopefully I'll get another couple of acceptances to top it out at 320(ish)